# Python, logging: use custom handler with dictionary configuration?

Tags: python, logging, configuration, dictionary, handler

this is about the logging module on Python 3.2 (GNU/Linux x86_64): is it possible to set a custom handler with dictionary configuration?
This is the code I'm trying:

```
import logging
import logging.config

class CustomHandler(logging.StreamHandler):
    pass

logconfig = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'CustomHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'custom': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
        }
    }
}
logging.config.dictConfig(logconfig)
logger = logging.getLogger('custom')
logger.error('Error message')
```

Which of course does not work. This is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/logging/config.py", line 390, in resolve
    found = self.importer(used)
ImportError: No module named CustomHandler

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/logging/config.py", line 569, in configure
    handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/logging/config.py", line 698, in configure_handler
    klass = self.resolve(config.pop('class'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/logging/config.py", line 403, in resolve
    raise v
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/logging/config.py", line 390, in resolve
    found = self.importer(used)
ValueError: Cannot resolve 'CustomHandler': No module named CustomHandler

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prova.py", line 91, in <module>
    logging.config.dictConfig(logconfig)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/logging/config.py", line 777, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/logging/config.py", line 574, in configure
    '%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'console': Cannot resolve 'CustomHandler': No module named CustomHandler
```

There is that `importer` method in the source which I really don't understand... Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to tell it where to find the `CustomHandler` class.  The string should contain the module (and possibly package) where it can be found.  If you are running this script directly, you can use `__main__.CustomHandler`.  Otherwise, use `your_module.CustomHandler`,  Where you replace `your_module` with the name of the module containing the class.